# MySQL - Small query issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a small query. When I execute it I am getting a error which is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key=stqq WHERE id=75' at line 1

My query is as follows

```
UPDATE roles SET name=stylistqq, key=stqq WHERE id=75
```

Comment: `key` is a reserved word in mySQL. You should use a different column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add quotes

```
UPDATE roles SET name='stylistqq', key='stqq' WHERE id=75
```

Answer (score 1):

Are stylistqq and stqq strings?  If so, they should have single quotes around them.  Pekka's recommendation to use a different column name other than key is also a good idea.  You can make MySQL take that string by putting backticks around it, but you'll *always* need them.